# newton's binomial

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Formulate Newton's binomial's solution and, using that, deduce that this formula is true: 
$${n\choose 0} + {n\choose 1} + \cdots + {n\choose n-1}+{n\choose n} = 2^n$$

I know that Newton's binomial is 
$$(a+b)^n={n\choose 0}a^n + {n\choose 1}a^{n-1}b +\cdots +{n\choose n-1}ab^{n-1} + {n\choose n}b^n$$

Can anybody help me with the second part? 
Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE.  Sorry but I don't understand your equations.  Here's a [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on formatting your equations.

Comment: Put $$a=b=1$$ in the identity

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$$2^n=(1+1)^n$$

Now apply binomial theorem on $(1+1)^n$.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that

$$(a+b)^n={n\choose 0}a^n + {n\choose 1}a^{n-1}b +\cdots +{n\choose n-1}ab^{n-1} + {n\choose n}b^n$$

Then when $a=b=1$, we have

$$(1+1)^n={n\choose 0} + {n\choose 1} + \cdots + {n\choose n-1}+{n\choose n}$$

And it follows from there.